# In a Bazel rule, how can I exclude certain input files from cache hit/miss detection

Tags: bazel

I have a bazel genrule running a custom tool to process certain set of input files and generate an output. The problem is that the custom tool takes a long time whenever it runs, but not every change in the input files set matters to the output of the custom tool. To detect whether the changes matter, I have another script that can parse through the inputs and quickly provide information if the custom tool's output is going to be any different.

I am not able to implement the above in Bazel. The way I would like to implement is as below

```
INPUT_FILES --------> [RULE1] --------> OUTPUT
     |                   ^
     |                   |
     |                   |
      --------------> [RULE2]
```

The `RULE2's` output should decide whether `RULE1` should run or not. But when it has to run, `INPUT_FILES` should be available to `RULE1`. So essentially only `RULE2's` output should be accounted for cache hit/miss calculations while executing `RULE1` and `INPUT_FILES` should be ignored. Is there a way to accomplish this?

EDIT:
I tried some experiments and I am able to implement this if I execute `RULE1` and `RULE2` with sandboxing disabled. That allows `RULE2` to access `RULE1`'s inputs without explicitly listing them. This seems hacky, but could be fine if there was a way to share a single sandbox for the rules instead of executing both without a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do what you're describing, however there are other strategies that might work for you. (There's an additional complication, I think, which is that `RULE2` wouldn't have access to the previous state of `INPUT_FILES`, so it wouldn't have anything to compare against to see what has changed in the inputs).

One strategy is to process the input files so that all the inconsequential  parts are removed, and the long-running tool in `RULE1` only ever sees the "important" stuff. This, of course, depends on exactly what your tools and rules do, but it might work.

As a simple example, you could have a tool that removes comments from code (in a way that preserves line numbers), and then the compiler action only ever sees code-only files. So, if you make a change to a comment, the input to the compiler is the same, and bazel skips the action.

This is similar to what bazel does to make building java rules more incremental. There's a tool that generates a "header jar" from java source code, which contains only the class interfaces, and upstream rules only see the header jar. That way, only changes to the interfaces of classes ever cause upstream rules to be rerun, and changes to comments or method implementations don't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it is a nice suggestion. I did consider it and in our case it is not possible to implement that because `RULE2` is doing more than just filtering the `INPUT_FILES`. It is more like `RULE2` does a quick elaboration, while `RULE1` does a deep elaboration. And the quick elaboration's sha could be a good indicator of whether `RULE1`'s output will be different. Also both rules need to use third-party eda tools, so not easy to port them to starlark.

Comment: Can `RULE2` produce the same output as `RULE1`? Is it just that sometimes, `RULE1` needs to be run to get the full / correct output? If so, then it might be possible to run the two binaries as the same action (i.e., make the action some binary that calls / coordinates the other two real binaries). Then they can do whatever they want within the same sandbox (as you mentioned in your edit)

Comment: They don't produce the same outputs. `RULE2` is more of a quick check as to whether a deep elaboration is going to give different result (i.e. whether the changes matter to `RULE1`). The problem with implementing a wrapper binary/script that chooses which rule to run is that I have to implement my own caching, which is what I am trying to avoid.

To elaborate in the example I have given, what `RULE2` can do is run a "quick elaboration" and publish the resultant sha. `RULE1` uses the sha to detect cache/hit or miss. If it is a miss, then `RULE1` runs using the `INPUT_FILES`.